# Update Observable timer in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I would like to change dynamically the Observable timer setting.

```
    this.speed = 1000;
    let timer = Observable.timer(1, this.speed);

    sub = timer.subscribe(t => {
        if (t == 10) {
            this.speed = 500;
        }
    });
```

If for example, after X seconds, I set the `this.speed = 500`.

The example above doesn't work. Is it possible, or I have to unsubscribe this one and create a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observable is currently created with the given time. You can't change that given time to affect the observable. So you need to unsubscribe and create another one.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this :

```
createDelayedObservable(delay: number): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.of('value').delay(delay);
}

sub  = createDelayedObservable(1000).subscribe(res => {/* ... */ });
```